# CORS settings in Spring boot does not work

Tags: spring, spring-boot, cors

I have Springboot (v 2.0) application. I enabled CORS in the application.properties as below.

```
management.endpoints.web.cors.allowed-origins=http://xxxx.yyyyy.me
management.endpoints.web.cors.allowed-methods=GET,POST
management.endpoints.web.cors.allowed-headers=Authorization,Cache-Control,Content-Type,Accept,X-Requested-With,Access-Control-Allow-Origin,Access-Control-Allow-Headers,Origin
management.endpoints.web.cors.exposed-headers=Access-Control-Expose-Headers,Authorization,Cache-Control,Content-Type,Access-Control-Allow-Origin,Access-Control-Allow-Headers,Origin
```

Also I had to remove the annotation @EnableWebMvc from the web config because I don't want to use Thymleaf templates (so I use my own add view controller like below.)

```
  @Override
  public void addViewControllers(ViewControllerRegistry registry)
  {
    registry.addViewController("/").setViewName("forward:/index.html");
    registry.addViewController("/myProfile").setViewName("forward:/index.html");
  }
```

also I added the CORS config bean in the main java class like below.

```
public WebMvcConfigurer corsConfigurer() {
    return new WebMvcConfigurer() {
      @Override
      public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
        registry.addMapping("/**").allowedOrigins("http://xxxx.yyyyy.me")
        .allowedHeaders("Authorization","Cache-Control","Content-Type","Accept","X-Requested-With","Access-Control-Allow-Origin","Access-Control-Allow-Headers","Origin")
          .exposedHeaders("Access-Control-Expose-Headers","Authorization","Cache-Control","Content-Type","Access-Control-Allow-Origin","Access-Control-Allow-Headers","Origin");
      }
    };
  }
```

Also in the web security, I added following:

```
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception
    {
       http.cors();
    }
```

But still no luck. When I get request from http://xxxx.yyyyy.me, I get CORS error like below.

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://abcde.com/api/traveller/findTravellers?fromDate=&toDate=&gender=&orderBy=&minAge=&maxAge=&keyword=&languages=&placeObj=&needAccommodation=false&haveAccommodation=false&needCar=false&haveCar=false&lookingFriends=false&withPhotoOnly=false&page=0&totalVisible=7&size=20&totalCount=0' from origin 'http://xxxx.yyyyy.me' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

Any idea how to fix this?
thanks a lot.

Comment: Is your CORS configuration code called at all? `WebMvcConfigurer` and `@EnableWebMvc` are closely coupled.

Comment: When I get request from http://xxxx.yyyyy.me,    to do this are you using any web browser on any restapi tool ?

Answer (score 4):

```
/**
 * CorsConfiguration Bean Configuration.
 * 
 * @return corsConfigurationSource.
 */
@Bean
public CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource() {
    final CorsConfiguration configuration = new CorsConfiguration();
    configuration.setAllowedOrigins(ImmutableList.of("*"));
    configuration.setAllowedMethods(ImmutableList.of(HttpMethod.HEAD.name(), HttpMethod.OPTIONS.name(), HttpMethod.GET.name(), HttpMethod.POST.name(), HttpMethod.PUT.name(), HttpMethod.DELETE.name(), HttpMethod.PATCH.name()));
    // setAllowCredentials(true) is important, otherwise:
    // The value of the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header in the response must not be the wildcard '*' when the
    // request's credentials mode is 'include'.
    configuration.setAllowCredentials(false);
    // setAllowedHeaders is important! Without it, OPTIONS preflight request
    // will fail with 403 Invalid CORS request
    configuration.setAllowedHeaders(ImmutableList.of(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION, HttpHeaders.CACHE_CONTROL, HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, HttpHeaders.ACCEPT, ORGA_ID));
    final UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
    source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", configuration);
    return source;
}
```

Comment: Where do I add this bean? In my main java class?

Answer (score 2):

I was having the same issue. What I had failed to understand is that `management.endpoints.web.cors` properties are simply for Spring Actuator management endpoints (e.g. `/health`).

To actually set the CORS properties for the regular service endpoints, one needs to programatically set them, as other answers here correctly show.

Answer (score 1):

I have used like below which is working perfectly fine. Please see my configuration file.

#### WebConfig.java

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class WebConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
        registry.addMapping("/**").allowedOrigins("*").allowedHeaders("*");
    }
}
```

Comment: This will work only if you have @EnableWebMvc. But I can't use that annotation

Comment: You can use @CrossOrigin in the Main class (or) Controllers.

Comment: I want to allow it in a single place. I don't want to add it to every controller

Comment: Add @CrossOrigin("*") in the main class.

Answer (score 1):

just try to add

```
public class CorsFilter implements Filter {
    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res, FilterChain chain)
            throws IOException, ServletException {
        HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) res;
        HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) req;
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", request.getHeader("Origin"));
        chain.doFilter(req, res);

    }
```

Comment: This is not secure, as you are copying origin header from request and sending it to response as allowed url! You should use some list of preconfigured allowed origins!

Answer (score 1):

Try below implementation. It always works for me. Replace * against Access-Control-Allow-Origin with your specific origin.

```
public class CORSFilter implements Filter {

    public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) res;
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, GET, PUT, OPTIONS, DELETE");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "3600");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Authorization, Origin, Accept, Access-Control-Request-Method, Access-Control-Request-Headers");

        chain.doFilter(req, res);
    }

    public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) {}

    public void destroy() {}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

We have on our project a bit fine-graned list and we configure allowed origins using configuration properties like this:

```
@Bean
public CorsFilter corsFilter() {
    final UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
    final CorsConfiguration config = jHipsterProperties.getCors();
    log.debug("Registering CORS filter");
    source.registerCorsConfiguration("/actuator/**", config);
    source.registerCorsConfiguration("/oauth2/**", config);
    source.registerCorsConfiguration("/management/**", config);
    source.registerCorsConfiguration("/v3/api-docs", config);
    source.registerCorsConfiguration("/swagger-ui/**", config);
    return new CorsFilter(source);
}
```

Note, that `jHipsterProperties` is instance which contains standard `CorsConfiguration` pojo defined in spring. You can use it freerly in your custom configuration and than use it in config file like this:

```
jhipster:
  cors:
    allowed-origins: "http://localhost:8100,http://localhost:9000"
    allowed-methods: "*"
    allowed-headers: "*"
    exposed-headers: "Authorization,Link,X-Total-Count,X-${jhipster.clientApp.name}-alert,X-${jhipster.clientApp.name}-error,X-${jhipster.clientApp.name}-params"
    allow-credentials: true
    max-age: 1800
```

Answer (score 0):

if you use Spring Security too, you should implement additional configuration in addition to [@codiallo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56537806/13315230).

So, inject CorsConfigurationSource bean into httpSecurity while configuring SecurityFilterChain.

```
//first inject corsConfigurationResource into the SecurityConfig class
class SecurityConfig(
    private val corsConfigurationResource: UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource
){

    @Bean
    fun securityFilterChain(
        http: HttpSecurity,
    ): SecurityFilterChain {

    return http.cors {
            it.configurationSource(corsConfigurationSource) //inject config into http security
        }
        //implement the rest
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Variants for register your self CORS processor depends on type of controller registration:

- default variant with `@Controller` used `RequestMappingHandlerMapping` for register CORS
- you used function style registration

By my opinion, you may try extend `AbstractUrlHandlerMapping` or another from hierarchy. For finding concrete implementation you can stay in debug in function `org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractUrlHandlerMapping#registerHandler`

---

Recently I self investigated looks like problem and used this method.
And my results:

- extended class `RequestMappingHandlerMapping`

  - overrided method `initCorsConfiguration` for making behavior of configured paths
  - registered it by function `io.github.iruzhnikov.webmvc.servlet.CorsPropWebMvcRegistrations#getRequestMappingHandlerMapping`
  - registered it by function `io.github.iruzhnikov.webmvc.servlet.CorsPropWebMvcConfigurationSupport#createRequestMappingHandlerMapping`
- extended class`io.github.iruzhnikov.webmvc.servlet.SpringMvcCorsConfigurer`

  - overrided method `addCorsMappings` for register new CorsConfig
  - registered id like of typical Bean